# How can I clear the input text after clicking

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how can I clear the input text after I made a click? By default, the value remains in the input field.

For example, I have an input text and the value is `TEXT`. When I perform a click, I want the input field to become empty.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

To remove the default text, on clicking the element:

```
$('input:text').click(
    function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });
```

I would, though, suggest using `focus()` instead:

```
$('input:text').focus(
    function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });
```

Which responds to keyboard events too (the tab key, for example). Also, you could use the `placeholder` attribute in the element:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="default text" />
```

Which will clear on focus of the element, and reappear if the element remains empty/user doesn't input anything.

Comment: I think the V in val should be lower case. ;-)

Comment: @David: LOL Answering SO questions on your iPhone. That's dedicated.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I agree that .val might be a bit of overkill in this scenario but I can see the simplicity in it that a new jQuery developer would appreciate.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I was on my own, on a bus, on a bank holiday Monday, in traffic on the A64 outside of York...what else was I going to be doing? =b

Comment: This was helpful for resetting input value for a search box, when the user closes the search box to hide it. Cheers

Answer (score 10):

**Update:** I took your saying "click" literally, which was a bit dumb of me. You can substitute `focus` for `click` in all of the below if you also want the action to happen when the user tabs to the input, which seems likely.

**Update 2:** My guess is that you're looking to do placeholders; see note and example at the end.

---

**Original answer**:

You can do this:

```
$("selector_for_the_input").click(function() {
    this.value = '';
});
```

...but that will clear the text regardless of what it is. If you only want to clear it if it's a specific value:

```
$("selector_for_the_input").click(function() {
    if (this.value === "TEXT") {
        this.value = '';
    }
});
```

So for example, if the input has an `id`, you could do:

```
$("#theId").click(function() {
    if (this.value === "TEXT") {
        this.value = '';
    }
});
```

Or if it's in a form with an `id` (say, "myForm") and you want to do this for every form field:

```
$("#myForm input").click(function() {
    if (this.value === "TEXT") {
        this.value = '';
    }
});
```

You may also be able to do it with delegation:

```
$("#myForm").delegate("input", "click", function() {
    if (this.value === "TEXT") {
        this.value = '';
    }
});
```

That uses [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to hook up a handler on the form but apply it to the inputs on the form, rather than hooking up a handler to each individual input.

---

If you're trying to do placeholders, there's more to it than that and you may want to find a good plug-in to do it. But here's the basics:

HTML:

```
<form id='theForm'>
  <label>Field 1:
    <input type='text' value='provide a value for field 1'>
  </label>
  <br><label>Field 2:
    <input type='text' value='provide a value for field 2'>
  </label>
  <br><label>Field 3:
    <input type='text' value='provide a value for field 3'>
  </label>
</form>
```

JavaScript using jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  // Save the initial values of the inputs as placeholder text
  $('#theForm input').attr("data-placeholdertext", function() {
    return this.value;
  });

  // Hook up a handler to delete the placeholder text on focus,
  // and put it back on blur
  $('#theForm')
    .delegate('input', 'focus', function() {
      if (this.value === $(this).attr("data-placeholdertext")) {
        this.value = '';
      }
    })
    .delegate('input', 'blur', function() {
      if (this.value.length == 0) {
        this.value = $(this).attr("data-placeholdertext");
      }
    });

});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ijuso4)

Of course, you can also use the new [`placeholder` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-placeholder) from HTML5 and only do the above if your code is running on a browser that doesn't support it, in which case you want to invert the logic I used above:

HTML:

```
<form id='theForm'>
  <label>Field 1:
    <input type='text' placeholder='provide a value for field 1'>
  </label>
  <br><label>Field 2:
    <input type='text' placeholder='provide a value for field 2'>
  </label>
  <br><label>Field 3:
    <input type='text' placeholder='provide a value for field 3'>
  </label>
</form>
```

JavaScript with jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  // Is placeholder supported?
  if ('placeholder' in document.createElement('input')) {
    // Yes, no need for us to do it
    display("This browser supports automatic placeholders");
  }
  else {
    // No, do it manually
    display("Manual placeholders");

    // Set the initial values of the inputs as placeholder text
    $('#theForm input').val(function() {
      if (this.value.length == 0) {
        return $(this).attr('placeholder');
      }
    });

    // Hook up a handler to delete the placeholder text on focus,
    // and put it back on blur
    $('#theForm')
      .delegate('input', 'focus', function() {
        if (this.value === $(this).attr("placeholder")) {
          this.value = '';
        }
      })
      .delegate('input', 'blur', function() {
        if (this.value.length == 0) {
          this.value = $(this).attr("placeholder");
        }
      });
  }

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }

});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ijuso4/3)

(Kudos to diveintohtml5.ep.io for the [`placholder` feature-detection code](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/detect.html#input-placeholder).)

Answer (score 4):

You could try this

```
$('#myFieldID').focus(function(){
  $(this).val('');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input:text").focus(function(){$(this).val("")});
```

Answer (score 2):

I am supposing you are trying to create a effect, where the textbox contains a label. And when the user click in the textbox, it disappears and lets the user input the text. You do not require Jquery for this.

```
<input type="text" value="Input Text" onfocus="this.value=''" onblur="(this.value=='')? this.value='Input Text':this.value;" />
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6PnYg/)

Comment: can you think of why this wouldn't work with a mail chimp embed code?

Comment: it's mailchimp embed code. I got it to work with placeholder, but couldn't replicate yours to work. You can see it at adelewellness.com.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
    **//Click The Button**    
    $('#yourButton').click(function(){

         **//What you want to do with your button**
         //YOUR CODE COMES HERE

         **//CLEAR THE INPUT**
         $('#yourInput').val('');

});
```

So first, you select your button with jQuery:

```
$('#button').click(function((){ //Then you get the input element $('#input')
    //Then you clear the value by adding:
    .val(' '); });
```

Comment: No worries.. let me explain.
**First click the button you want to use to clear the input**
`$('#button').click(function({
     **Then select the input and set value to --> ' ' <-- empty **
     $('#input').val(' ');
}));`

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery ...

```
$('#submitButtonsId').click(
    function(){
        $(#myTextInput).val('');
    });
```

Using pure Javascript ...

```
var btn = document.getElementById('submitButton');
btn.onclick = function(){ document.getElementById('myTextInput').value="" };
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an elegant way to do this:

```
<input type="text" value="Search" name="" 
       onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}" 
       onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Pesquisa';}"/>
```

In this way, if you type anything inside the search box, it won't be deleted when click inside the box again.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> function submitForm()
> {
>     if (testSubmit())
>     {
>         document.forms["myForm"].submit(); //first submit
>         document.forms["myForm"].reset(); //and then reset the form values
>     }
> } </script> <body>
> <form method="get" name="myForm">
>
>     First Name: <input type="text" name="input1"/>
>     <br/>
>     Last Name: <input type="text" name="input2"/>
>     <br/>
>     <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()"/>
> </form>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you need placeholder like behavior. you can use this.

```
$("selector").data("DefaultText", SetYourDefaultTextHere);
// You can also define the DefaultText as attribute and access that using attr() function

$("selector").focus(function(){
if($(this).val() == $(this).data("DefaultText"))
   $(this).val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("input[name=search-mini]").on("search", function() {
 //do something for search
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to use this since I have the same issue which got fixed.

```
$('input:text').focus(
    function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });
```

Comment: You shoud add some explainations. We all want to know why your solution is better.

Answer (score -1):

```js
  $('.mybtn').on('click',
      function(){
          $('#myinput').attr('value', '');
      }
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <button class="mybtn">CLEAR</button>
  <input type="text" id="myinput" name="myinput" value="ааааааааа">
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score -2):

```
    enter code here<form id="form">
<input type="text"><input type="text"><input type="text">

<input type="button" id="new">
</form>
<form id="form1">
<input type="text"><input type="text"><input type="text">

<input type="button" id="new1">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#new").click( function(){
        //alert("fegf");
    $("#form input").val('');
    });

      $("#new1").click( function(){
        //alert("fegf");
    $("#form1 input").val('');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What does this add that the other answers didn't?