# JavaScript var getElementById if statement not working

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, var

I am rather new on JavaScript and I can't figure out how to code this in JavaScript/html:
I basically need an option so the customer can pick the language he wants and based on that selection another pick list appears where he can chose the available promo/item for that language.

```
<script>
function PromoLanguage(){
var language = document.getElementById('languages');
var a = language.selectedIndex;
if (a == 1){
document.getElementById('French').style.display = inline;
}
else if (a == 2){
document.getElementById('English').style.display = inline;
}
else if (a == 3){
document.getElementById('German').style.display = inline;
}
}    
</script>    
<body>
<select onchange="PromoLanguage()" id='languages'>
<option>French</option>
<option>English</option>
<option>German</option>
</select>

<select id='English' style='display: none'>
<option>ENGLISHPROMO1</option>
<option>ENGLISHPROMO2</option>
<option>...</option>

<select id='French' style='display: none'>
<option>FRENCHPROMO1</option>
<option>FRENCHPROMO2</option>
<option>...</option>

<select id='German' style='display: none'>
<option>GERMANPROMO1</option>
<option>GERMANPROMO2</option>
<option>...</option>
```

Here is another thing I tried and it work if I select the 2nd item (English) and now I don't know how to make it do something similar when the customer would select French or German.

```
document.getElementById('languages').onchange = function() {
var display = this.selectedIndex == 2 ? "Inline" : "none";
document.getElementById('English').style.display = display;
}
```

Comment: what isn't working? whats the question?

Comment: You should use `function`, `var`, `if`,  `else`, `document` in lowercase.

Comment: please format your code

Comment: Also `else () {} ` does not exist.

Comment: Do you actually know Javascript?

Comment: Besides all of that, to display those select elements, you should be setting their display property to `inline-block`, not some undefined variable called "display."

Comment: and once all of that is fixed, the browser console is your friend.

Comment: JavaScript has zero-based indexing; so you need to test for `a === 0` as well. But I'm not sure what your question is. This may not matter, but I'd argue that you should use lower-case `if` and `else`.

Comment: Sorry guys, I typed the code from my iPad as I am travelling and it put the high case automatically. I am basically trying to find a code where the customer can pick a language from a pick list and depending what language he picks another pick list shows up so he can chose the promo in that language

Answer (score 0):

use something like this to get the selected option

```
 $('select').on('change', function() {
    var show = $('select option:selected').val();
     if(show ==something){
    //  do something
      }
});
```

if this is what u are asking for

for javascript:

```
         <select  id="select_id">
        <option value="0">French</option>
        <option value="1">English</option>
        </select>
       <select  id="promo" class="hidden">
        <option value="0">promo1</option>
        <option value="1">promo2</option>
        </select>
      document.getElementById('promo').style.display = 'none';

   var select_id = document.getElementById("select_id");
   var selected =select_id.options[select_id.selectedIndex].text;
     if(selected ==French){
    document.getElementById('promo').style.display = 'block';
      }
```

and you can do same stuff selected promo

Comment: I don't see a jQuery tag, and the OP seems to be new to JavaScript, don't expect him or her to know jQuery.

Comment: Right @Spencer Wieczorek. I am a newbie... But somehow I really need to solve that problem and can't figure it out.

Comment: @Imacange  edited my ans for javascript hope this will help you

Comment: 'do something'? That's your solution?

Comment: @David i m not supposed to do all f his programming .

Comment: Tks sumit, I tried your JavaScript and replaced the "something" with: if (selected == 1){ document.getElementById('French').style.display = 'block'; } but even that does not work... :(

Comment: @imacange i have edited my answer this might help you

Comment: Tks @SumitShrestha i have tried your code but it does not go. I tried it with Firefox as well as safari with the try it editor but no luck. http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/tryit.asp? Did you try it yourself? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Note that I've changed your HTML (closing the `<select>` elements, and adding a class-name to those elements that are related as 'language-options':

```
<select id='languages'>
  <option>French</option>
  <option>English</option>
  <option>German</option>
</select>

<select id='English' class='languageOption'>
  <option>ENGLISHPROMO1</option>
  <option>ENGLISHPROMO2</option>
  <option>...</option>
</select>

<!-- other select elements removed for brevity -->
```

I've also completely changed your function, to one that works slightly more cleanly (though later in the answer I'll explain the problems with your original implementation, beyond the lack of efforts to fix your iPad's insistence on grammar).

This is a simple function that seems to work:

```
function PromoLanguage() {
  // I've changed the variable-names, to something meaningful,
  // which makes them easier to keep track of within the function:
  var select = document.getElementById('languages'),
    index = select.selectedIndex,
    // you don't need the <option>, you need the <option>-value,
    // if no value is set the value is the option's text:
    language = select.options[index].value;

  // using Array.prototype.forEach, and Function.prototype.call
  // to iterate over the array-like NodeList returned by 
  // document.querySelectorAll() (which is supported in IE8,
  // whereas getElementsByClassName() is not);
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.languageOption'), function (opt) {
    // the first element of the anonymous function is the array-element
    // itself, in this case a DOM-node, the <select> elements found by
    // their class-name.
    // here we're setting their display property to an invalid value,
    // which removes the display property from their style attribute,
    // and allows the CSS to style them once more:
    opt.style.display = '';
  });

  // Finding the <select> element with the appropriate id,
  // and showing it:
  document.getElementById(language).style.display = 'block';
}

// in-line JavaScript is obtrusive, this binds the change
// event-handler to the element with an id='languages',
// and binds the named-function (note the lack of parentheses)
// as the event-handler:
document.getElementById('languages').addEventListener('change', PromoLanguage);
```

```js
function PromoLanguage() {
  var select = document.getElementById('languages'),
    index = select.selectedIndex,
    language = select.options[index].value;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.languageOption'), function (opt) {
    opt.style.display = '';
  });
  document.getElementById(language).style.display = 'block';
}

document.getElementById('languages').addEventListener('change', PromoLanguage);
```

```css
select {
  display: block;
}
select.languageOption {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id='languages'>
  <option>French</option>
  <option>English</option>
  <option>German</option>
</select>

<select id='English' class='languageOption'>
  <option>ENGLISHPROMO1</option>
  <option>ENGLISHPROMO2</option>
  <option>...</option>
</select>

<select id='French' class='languageOption'>
  <option>FRENCHPROMO1</option>
  <option>FRENCHPROMO2</option>
  <option>...</option>
</select>

<select id='German' class='languageOption'>
  <option>GERMANPROMO1</option>
  <option>GERMANPROMO2</option>
  <option>...</option>
</select>
```

Your original code:

```
Function PromoLanguage() {
  Var language = document.getElementById('languages');
  Var a = language.selectedIndex;
  If(a == 1) {
    Document.getElementById('French').style.display = display;
  }
  Else
  if (a == 2) {
    Document.getElementById('English').style.display = display;
  }
  Else
  if (a == 3) {
    Document.getElementById('German').style.display = display;
  }
}
```

JavaScript is case-sensitive, `Var` should be `var`, `If` should be `if`; typing on an iPad, and not paying attention to the created-errors is [understandable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777674/how-can-i-clear-the-input-text-when-i-clicked/5777695#comment6620249_5777695), but it's not good to post broken code with additional breaks since that obscures your own mistakes.

Now:

```
var a = language.selectedIndex;
if(a == 1) {
```

Here, you're missing out the first-option, which will be - thanks to zero-indexing in JavaScript - `a == 0`.

Also, the `selectedIndex` will always be a number, so you should use `===` to ensure you're testing for exact equality (that the number is the same, and that both arguments are numbers).

Then:

```
document.getElementById('French').style.display = display;
```

Here you're assigning a variable to the element's `display` property; you haven't defined that property then it will do nothing except raise an error (one would hope). Had you typed this in a browser with an error-console (though allegedly iPad Safari *has* one, I've never worked out how to access it), you could have checked the error that it reported, which would have - hopefully - led you to the problem (had your code not been stymied by incorrect capitalizations beforehand).

Comment: Thanks for the care @David Thomas. I really see that you spent the time to care for my problem. Unfortunately the code does not seem to be working. I really tried and even copy/paste it into the w3 editor (http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp) and it does not go. Everything is showing up. I do see that I messed up the code on my original post and the truth is that I ve spent almost a whole day trying to figure that one out that i totally mixed up different codes at the end and got totally confused. Anyway, tks for putting some light into my confusion, I think that I am getting close.